# ASP.NET Send email with Parallels Plesk Panel 11.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, plesk, smtpclient

I'd like to create a web application in ASP.NET C# MVC 5 using Parallels Plesk Panel 11.5 using HostGator.

Is that possible?  I'd like my web app to send an email whenever someone fills out a particular form.  Where can I go to find out the SMTP server information?  What do I need to know to set that up?

I'd appreciate any other help, links, or guides you can provide as I set this up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is might be too late but to help the others;

```
 public static void SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string body)
 {
    try
    {
        const string fromEmail = "yourEmail@YourDomain.com";
        var message = new MailMessage
        {
           From = new MailAddress(fromEmail),
           To = { toEmail },
           Subject = subject,
           Body = body,
           DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
        };              
        using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("webmail.YourDomain.com")) 
        {                   
           smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("yourEmail@YourDomain.com", "your email password");
           smtpClient.Port = 25;
           smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;  
           smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception excep)
    {
      //ignore it or you can retry .
    }
}
```

This worked for me on Plesk Onyx 17.5.3

Comment: How to send a html text? Now when I'm using this, it sends message but a plain text not in html format.

Comment: I used  IsBodyHtml = true, in order to do this. Thanks